# Rails model as_json overwriting default values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying overwrite default model values for json but instead of overwriting it create duplicate hash

My model:

```
class HomeScreenButton < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product_category    
    validates :product_category_id, :x, :y, :presence => true
  attr_accessible :product_category_id, :x, :y

  def as_json(options={})
    hash = super(options)
    hash.merge({
      :product_category_id => "fdfd"
    })
  end
end
```

My controller:

```
def index
    @home_screen_buttons = HomeScreenButton.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @home_screen_buttons}
    end
end
```

When I'm opening json it shows me duplicate for product_category_id:    `[{"created_at":"2013-03-17T11:14:32Z","id":1,"product_category_id":5,"updated_at":"2013-03-17T11:14:32Z","x":300,"y":200,"product_category_id":"dfdffff"}]`

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to merge hashes

```
def as_json(options={})
  hash = super(options)
  hash[:product_category_id] = "fdfd"
  hash
end
```

Comment: It still makes duplicates. Using "product_category_id" instead of :product_category_id solved my problem in both examples.